# Bad Certificate issue in Karate HTTPS calls

Tags: karate

Few tests pass and few tests fail with below error. In fact, one Scenario is passing and another is failing in same Feature with request and response json only difference between both.

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
Received fatal alert: bad_certificate, http call failed after 583 milliseconds for url: https://host.com:8080/api
```

I have `karate.configure('ssl', {trustAll: true});` in my `karate-config.js`.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: in my opinion, no one can help you unless the problem can be replicated. no other suggestions other than you scan other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+SSLHandshakeException